# Laravel 5.4 - call another job once job is completed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, job-scheduling

I have some problem generating another job queue once job is completed.

As described in laravel docs, I am using `JobProcessed $event` to detect the event and it is in AppServiceProvider.php like below

```
    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        $payload = $event->job->getRawBody();
        $payload = json_decode($payload);
        $data = $payload->data;
        $command = unserialize($data->command);
        if($command->queue == 'importInsights' && in_array($command->getInsightsOption(), ['item1', 'item2'])) {
            try {
                Artisan::queue("sync:insights", [
                    'insightOption' => 'some option',
                    '--day' => 'test date',
                    '--queue' => 'syncInsights'
                ]);
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                Log::error("Failed to call insights queue" . $e->getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

For my local machine it's working, as I'm on windows and don't have installed redis, but in test server we have redis and there nothing is happening. 
First job is working fine without issue, but nothing happened for 2-nd one. I have tried with `Artisan::call` also, no luck. If I wil try instead in event handler put simple code like  `Log::error("Test for queue handler");` this will work without any problems.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.